# excute function and append method at same time javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Hello everyone I am using corresponding dropdown script from this website
http://www.javascriptsource.com/forms/country-state-city-drop-down-list.html

it's working fine but

**Problem**
I am generating dropdown & textbox when user is entering/selecting anything
I am trying to integrate this script in my code when first time i am selecting(dropdown) it is not changing corresponding dropdown second time it is working fine because fist time it's excuting .append method how can i excute both .append and function at same time

dynamically generated box

```
    $(document).one("change", '.txtInput4', function() {
  var len = $('.txtInput4').length;
 // alert(len);



  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $('.mattressbox5').append('<div class="form-group custom-form-group"><label for="name" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Do you have back pain </label><div class="col-sm-4"><select class="txtInput5 box-width personalize-form" name="backpain"  id="country" onchange="setStates();" required> <option value="">Select Backpain</option><option value="Canada">No</option><option value="Mexico">Sometimes</option><option value="United States">Yes</option></select></div></div>');
  }
});



$(document).one("change", '.txtInput5', function() {
  var len = $('.txtInput5').length;
 // alert(len);

  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $('.mattressbox6').append('<div class="form-group custom-form-group"><label for="name" class="col-sm-5 control-label">My Comfort Preference is </label><div class="col-sm-4"><select name="state" id="state"  class="txtInput6 box-width personalize-form"  required> <option value="">Select mattress preference</option></select></div></div>');
  }
});
```

please suggest something

Comment: Why $(document).one("change", '.txtInput5', function() {} have one() instead of on() ?

Comment: it's jquery method to append one time only check here http://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

```
 onBlur="setStates();" //is working fine
```

before that i was using onchange it was first executing append and second time calling function.